# How can we close websockets connection when component unmount?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, mount, unmount

I am having a small bug in my application which causing a big problem. In my react-vite application, I have integrated WebSocket to get the live status of a particular thing.

**Problem**: When a user views the component, it should send the `active` status to the server. When the user leaves the page, the component should send `inactive` only. But in my current implementation, it sends the active status first, then when I leave it sends `inactive` and then `active`. I tried to send `active` and `inactive` only. But it doesn't work. As soon as it sends the "inactive" status, it sends the `active` afterward.

**Why I am not closing the WebSocket?**
I tried to close it. But the method is not accepted for now from the `react-use-websocket` package.

**What I am looking for?**
I am looking for only sending the `active` status when the component mounts and `inactive` when the component unmounts.

I am looking for a solid solution or suggestion from you guys. Anything from your end would be appreciated. Open to learn anything. Thanks in advance.

The package I have used here for WebSocket: `react-use-websocket`

**Code:**

Server Url:

```
const socketUrl = `wss://my-web-server/v1/api/wall/set/user/status/${token}/${id}`;
```

Here's how I use it:

```
  const { sendJsonMessage, readyState, } = useWebSocket(socketUrl, { share: true });
```

Sending the message:

```
  //common function for sending message
  const sendJsonMessageToServer = useCallback((status: any) => {
  if (readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    sendJsonMessage(status);
  }
},
[readyState, sendJsonMessage]);

 //useEffect for checking if the component get mounted or not. 
  useEffect(() => {
sendJsonMessageToServer({ status: "active" });
return () => {
  if (readyState === ReadyState.OPEN) {
    sendJsonMessageToServer({ status: "inactive" });
  }
}; }, [readyState, sendJsonMessageToServer]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = ({ token, id }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const socketUrl = `wss://my-web-server/v1/api/wall/set/user/status/${token}/${id}`;
    const socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);

    socket.onopen = () => {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'active' }));
    };

    return () => {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'inactive' }));
      socket.close();
    };
  }, [token, id]);

  return <div>Your component content</div>;
};

export default YourComponent;
```

**The problem you're facing might be due to the asynchronous nature of WebSocket connections and the timing of component unmounting in React.**

Try this:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useWebSocket, ReadyState } from 'react-use-websocket';

const YourComponent = ({ token, id }) => {
  const socketUrl = `wss://my-web-server/v1/api/wall/set/user/status/${token}/${id}`;
  const { sendJsonMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(socketUrl, { share: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readyState === ReadyState.OPEN) {
      sendJsonMessage({ status: 'active' });
    }

    return () => {
      if (readyState === ReadyState.OPEN) {
        sendJsonMessage({ status: 'inactive' });
      }
    };
  }, [sendJsonMessage, readyState]);

  return <div>Your component content</div>;
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks, brother, I followed this. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide the error you are getting.

Comment: I don't get any error here. I can see that it sends the `active` status to the server. When I left the component, it sent the `inactive` status and afterward, it sent the `active` status again. Thus my user status remains active. That's the issue.